# Convert date format MM-DD-YY to MM-dd-yyyy in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-expression

How can I convert date format `MM-DD-YY` to `MM-dd-yyyy`?

**For example:**

CurrentDate is `11-30-15` - `(MM-DD-YY)`

Expected output is `11-30-2015` - `(MM-dd-yyyy)`

I want to set `Expression` to for this date value in format `MM-dd-yyyy`

I tried below but not worked for me,

`=Format(Fields!CurrentDate.Value, "MM-dd-yyyy")`

**Note:** I do not want to convert it into `MM-dd-yyyy` from `Stored Procedure`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `CurrentDate` was a `string`, not a `date` so I need to convert it to a date first, then formatted it and worked fine now.

```
=Format(CDate(Fields!CurrentDate.Value), "MM/dd/yyyy")
```

Thanks you so much for your views.

Comment: Why was your date being stored (or returned) as a string, instead of a proper date type?